# Is there search and replace history in Vim?

Tags: search

We can retrieve search and replace history on IDEs and text editors.

Likewise is there a search history or a way to retrieve previously searched expression in Vim?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yes, you have the `history` command:

```
:history /
```

Note that it can be used for `/`, `:`, `=`, `>`, `?`, `@`, `all`, `cmd`, `debug`, `expr`, `input` and `search`.

Alternatively you can use the `q:`, `q/` and `q?` commands to see previously entered commands and searches on a sepearate buffer. You can then modify as you want and replay them by pressing `<CR>`.

See `:h :history`, `:h q:`.

Comment: Thanks. Previously I tried just `:history` which was bit closer.

Comment: As for replace, one can look at `q:`. It's not exclusive to replaces, but it's a real buffer, so all of vim's power works there.

Comment: @PhilippFrank, I'll add this to the answer, thanks

Comment: Related [Vimcasts](http://vimcasts.org/) episode: [Refining search patterns with the command-line window](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/refining-search-patterns-with-the-command-line-window/)

Comment: This answer works great- if you want fast/fuzzy search through your search/command history, you can also use `:History/` and `:History:` using the [fzf](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim) plugin

Answer (score 2):

You can use `:history s` for search history. As a shortcut, you can use `:his s`. Same way for command line history also.

Answer (score 2):

Just hit `/` and then `Ctrl-f` to bring up the search history directly under your cursor, scroll with motion keys and `Enter` at whichever phrase you need to return to. Since I discovered that `Ctrl-f` list I've never used awful distant Arrow keys to scroll over.

Comment: Also q/, q:, etc., mentioned in the accepted answer

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Yes, `q/` is the same and even simpler.  The only benefit of `Ctrl-f` is when you're already in the search mode `/` (or other mode) and want to bring up the history. Anyway thank you for the indication.