# How to search and replace in the history

Tags: search, replace, command-history

Is there a way edit command line or search history?
I have read [Is there search and replace history in vim?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/7713/is-there-search-and-replace-history-in-vim) and tried using q: to open the history and do changes there, but all it seems to be able to do is take an edited line, execute it and append it to the history.

What I want to do is just replace a line in history (in-place) without necessarily executing it.

Use case: I try to create a plugin, that appends words under the cursor to the search (when the user presses a button). The most part is done by changing the @/ register. But I also want to update the original search command so that a user can actually find the command that would issue the modified search. I could simply re-execute the search, but then the history would get flooded.

**Example**:

*Buffer*: This is some fine text in the buffer.

*User enters*: "/some", the cursor goes to "some" and the last line in search history will contain "/some". Then, the user moves the cursor to "text", presses a certain key and text is added to the search term. So now, the search term would be "/some\|text".

I would like to change/overwrite the last line in search history to be "/some\|text".

Comment: I imagine you could use `histadd()`, `histget()`, and `histdel()` function to create such a behavior. See `:h histadd()`

Comment: @PeterRincker: Hey, this is exactly what I was looking for. Thank your! And it seems to be available in NeoVim as well. NICE! If you make that an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can edit the search history with the following,: `histadd()`, `histget()`, and `histdel()`.

See `:h histadd()` for more help.

Answer (score 0):

Vim stores both the command history and the search history and many other things like registers and jumplists in `~/.viminfo`.
You can remove/edit entries from the history by deleting/changing the corresponing lines in the file.